# Issue in Inspecting elements using Appium for Hybrid application

Tags: appium

We are facing below issues in our project in finding elements for Hybrid application using  Appium

Page Scroll issue – On scrolling the page , Element position inspected via      Appium is different from the location where they are actually visible on      screen. Please refer screenshot - here 10th Pass element is      inspected at yellow highlighted area.
Overlay Issue – We are not able to inspect the overlay elements . Appium is treating      overlay as single element . Please refer screenshot  – here it is inspecting      “delete video ” overlay as 1 element and unable to inspect proceed/cancel      buttons separately .
Please help and thanks in advance.

Page scroll issue

[image: Page scroll issue]

Overlay Issue

[image: Overlay Issue]

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome developer to inspect the hybrid content in app.What you are seeing in the appium desktop is native context.

Comment: Thanks will try this